# SQL syntax error. Creating of Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mybatis

I've started to create a Stored Procedure with MySQL.
And then I would like to make migration:up (MyBatis).

```
mvn migration:up -Dmigration.path=/path/to/repository
```

Here is my Stored Procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_tips;


CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_tips`(gspId INTEGER, gameID INTEGER)
BEGIN

DECLARE @start_datetime = getdate();
DECLARE @execution_time_in_seconds int;
DECLARE @LID int;
INSERT INTO sp_logs(spName, startTime) VALUES(`add_tips`, @start_datetime);
SET @LID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
...
/*some code goes here*/
...
@execution_time_in_seconds = datediff(SECOND,@start_datetime,getdate())
UPDATE sp_logs
SET executionTime = @execution_time_in_seconds
WHERE logId = @LID;

END
```

After that migration:up command executed

I receive an error

```
Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@start_datetime = getdate();
[INFO] DECLARE @execution_time_in_seconds int;
[INFO] DECLARE @LI' at line 4
```

Comment: You have odd single quotes being used. Remove them and use the standard single quote ' instead of `

Comment: There is no surprise that you are getting a syntax error.  Your stored procedure is written using SQL Sever syntax in many places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. The final code looks like:

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_tips;


    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_tips`(gspId INTEGER, gameID INTEGER)
    BEGIN

   DECLARE start_datetime DATETIME;
   DECLARE execution_time TIME;
   DECLARE lid INTEGER;
    SET start_datetime = NOW();
    INSERT INTO sp_logs(spName,startTime) values('add_tips', start_datetime);
    SET lid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    ...
    /*some code goes here*/
    ...
SET execution_time = TIMEDIFF(NOW(), start_datetime); 
UPDATE sp_logs
SET executionTime = execution_time
WHERE logId = lid;

    END;
```

The problem was `END;`

Answer (score 2):

you should change the 'delimiter'

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_tips;

delimiter //


CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_tips`(gspId INTEGER, gameID INTEGER)
BEGIN

DECLARE @start_datetime = getdate();
DECLARE @execution_time_in_seconds int;
DECLARE @LID int;
INSERT INTO sp_logs(spName, startTime) VALUES(`add_tips`, @start_datetime);
SET @LID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
...
/*some code goes here*/
...
@execution_time_in_seconds = datediff(SECOND,@start_datetime,getdate())
UPDATE sp_logs
SET executionTime = @execution_time_in_seconds
WHERE logId = @LID;

END //

delimiter ;
```

Comment: I was added DELIMITER // , DELIMITER ; . So now the ERROR is: Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter //         CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_tips`(g' at line 1